# scroll down button not coming twice, html

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website from some questions found here, and I want to add a scroll down below button. here, I have tried to implement my own code, and it works.

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Avoiding overlay */

.main {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* The progress container */

.progress-container {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}


/* The progress bar */

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  width: 0%;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.4418ff70835bb7e45f3b5d83c7ff5f5e?rik=bD4DENSEINH8%2bA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwallup.net%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2017%2f03%2f28%2f439234-sports_car-vehicle-Lamborghini-Italian_Supercars.jpg&ehk=kG5ZwFnums33xnh3qxViA8B4WZ73wbUAjrictsOSXbU%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg-image1 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.dI7owNNNwtRKg0Ho4kZNIAHaEK?pid=ImgDet&rs=1");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg-image2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.WZziNQ9wRCIosw1FGPkJsAHaEK?pid=ImgDet&rs=1");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-text1 {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bg-text2 {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


.demo a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: #fff;

  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.demo a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

#section04 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#section04 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}

p {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="app.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#contact">About</a>
  </div>



  <div class="header">
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="Bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='main'></div>
    <div class="bg-image"></div>

    <div class="bg-text">
      <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
      <h1>My car website</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div id='p1'>
      <p>Car website!</p>
    </div>
      
    <center>
      <section id="section04" class="demo">
        <a href="#p1"><span></span>Scroll</a>
      </section>
    </center>     

    <div class="bg-image1"></div>
    <div class="bg-text1">
      <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
      <h1>My car website</h1>
    </div>

    <center>
      <section id="section04" class="demo">
        <a href="#p1"><span></span>Scroll</a>
      </section>
    </center>    

    <div class="bg-image2"></div>
    <div class="bg-text2">
      <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
      <h1>My car website</h1>
    </div>

<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {changeOnScroll()};

function changeOnScroll() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("Bar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, when you run the program, you see a 'scroll' down button. when you click on it, you will get smooth scrolled to the next div. but, if you see the program, I have tried to add the scroll down button to the next div also, but it is not coming. why is it happening ? is there any solution?

Comment: because you're using the same **ID** for both scrolls

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .natis {

        width: 25%;
        height: 150px;
        border: 2px solid black;

        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        overflow: scroll;
        text-align: center;


    }
</style>



<div class="natis">
    <h1>This is example </h1>
    <p> i am accusam dolore consetetur dolor amet duo lorem amet duo et, et lorem sed magna aliquyam, consetetur sit
        no vero dolore lorem, consetetur stet et sanctus diam takimata dolor stet, dolor sadipscing consetetur
        tempor sanctus elitr sit et accusam. Sadipscing lorem ut sadipscing erat, diam sanctus dolor sed ipsum magna
        consetetur labore stet takimata, eirmod consetetur dolore dolore dolor et consetetur, ipsum elitr justo
        consetetur dolores amet, elitr amet duo diam amet et justo justo est. Sit stet nonumy vero no et accusam sit
        justo vero, et elitr kasd diam lorem dolor erat lorem. Sed ipsum sed rebum stet sed. nonumy diam no dolore
        et gubergren. Ipsum gubergren vero labore diam, invidunt takimata sed sadipscing erat elitr magna clita
        sadipscing takimata. Nonumy nonumy dolor diam sit justo et erat, sanctus sed erat amet diam no consetetur
        kasd eos. Amet gubergren et aliquyam consetetur. Et no sed dolores labore. </p>
</div>
```